# Convert Hyperlinked text to Media Wiki friendly syntax. Remove extra text

Tags: vba, ms-word, mediawiki

Currently have a Word document with Hyperlinked text. When copied into MediaWiki, it strips the hyperlink.

```
Sub Demo()
With ActiveDocument
  While .Hyperlinks.Count > 0
    .Hyperlinks(1).Range.InsertBefore "[" & .Hyperlinks(1).Address & " " & .Hyperlinks(1).TextToDisplay & "]"
    .Hyperlinks(1).Delete
  Wend
End With
End Sub
```

This VB Macro will turn the Word Hyperlink into what I need, but I cannot remove the 2nd Text as display. It will turn [A Link like this](https://stackoverflow.com/) into the plain text [https://stackoverflow.com/ Stack Link here] Stack Link here .

I am looking for the quick bit of code that will remove the second "Stack Link here" after the "]" . As the correct syntax for MediaWiki is [www.yourlinkhere.com ClickableTextHere]

EDIT: Currently have a solution that throws a runtime error, but managed to add an exception in. Code below:

```
Sub ConvertHyperlinksToWikiFormat5Error()
    With ActiveDocument
        On Error Resume Next ' Ignore runtime errors temporarily
        While .Hyperlinks.Count > 0
            Dim hyperlink As hyperlink
            Set hyperlink = .Hyperlinks(1)
            
            ' Create the modified Wiki format text
            Dim modifiedText As String
            modifiedText = "[" & hyperlink.Address & " " & hyperlink.TextToDisplay & "]"
            
            ' Replace the original text with the modified one
            hyperlink.Range.Text = modifiedText
            
            ' Delete the hyperlink
            hyperlink.Delete
        Wend
        On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling to default
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls try.

```
Sub Demo()
    With ActiveDocument
        While .Hyperlinks.Count > 0
            .Hyperlinks(1).Range.Text = "[" & .Hyperlinks(1).Address & " " & .Hyperlinks(1).TextToDisplay & "]"
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.Text property (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.text?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm157155328)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the response. This is shorter than the solution I concocted but when I get some time I'll give it a try and report back.